# DataFlow Job Startup Takes Too Long When triggered from Composer

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a static pipeline with the following architecture:

```
 main.py
 setup.py
 requirements.txt
 module 1
   __init__.py
   functions.py
 module 2
   __init__.py
   functions.py
 dist
   setup_tarball
```

The setup.py and requirements.txt contain the non-native PyPI and local functions which would be used by the Dataflow worker node. The dataflow options are written as follows:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText, WriteToText
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from module2.functions import function_to_use

dataflow_options = ['--extra_package=./dist/setup_tarball','temp_location=<gcs_temp_location>', '--runner=DataflowRunner', '--region=us-central1', '--requirements_file=./requirements.txt]
```

So then the pipeline will run something like this:

```
options = PipelineOptions(dataflow_options)
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
transform = (p | ReadFromText(gcs_url) | beam.Map(function_to_use) | WriteToText(gcs_output_url))
```

Running this locally takes Dataflow around 6 minutes to complete, where most of the time goes to worker startup. I tried getting this code automated with Composer and re-arranged the architecture as follows: my main (dag) function in dags folder, the modules in plugins, and setup_tarball and requirements.txt in data folder... So the only parameters that really changed are:

```
'--extra_package=/home/airflow/gcs/data/setup_tarball'
'--requirements_file=/home/airflow/gcs/data/requirements.txt'
```

When I try running this modified code in Composer, it will work... but it'll take much, much longer... Once the worker starts up, it will take anywhere from 20-30 minutes before actually running the pipeline (which is only a few seconds).. This is much longer than triggering Dataflow from my local code, which was taking only 6 minutes to complete. I realize this question is very general, but since the code works, I don't think it's related to the Airflow task itself. Where would be a reasonable place to start looking at for troubleshooting this problem? At the Airflow level, what can be modified? How does Composer (Airflow) interact with Dataflow, and what can potentially cause this bottleneck?

Comment: a possibility here is that your worker is reinstalling and rebuilding python dependencies. Can you look at worker-startup logs in Dataflow to see if most of the t8ime in the slow job is spent installing dependencies?

If so, we can try to figure out a way to skip thath

Comment: Hi Pablo, thanks for your suggestion. So when I look at the job logs, the worker successfully starts, but it spends roughly 30 mins before executing. It is likely that it is reinstalling and rebuilding.. My setup file is required to install local modules, while my 'requirements.txt' has two PyPI modules that are not native to worker nodes.. do you think there may be some conflict there? I am just surprised that I would not ahev this problem when I run it locally. Please let me know if there's any additional info you need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was associated with Composer itself. The fix was to increase the capacity of Composer, i.e., increase vCPUs. Not sure why this would be the case, so if anyone has an idea for the foundation behind this issue, your input would be much appreciated!